# How to create a list made out of matrices in python?

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix

I have the list below filled with matrices:

```
incSplitList = [numpy.zeros((4, 4))] * nmbDurations
```

Which looked like this before I started using lists:

```
incSplit = numpy.zeros((4, 4)) 
incSplit2 = numpy.zeros((4, 4))
incSplit3 = numpy.zeros((4, 4))
incSplit4 = numpy.zeros((4, 4))
incSplit5 = numpy.zeros((4, 4))
```

Now I need to compress and pythonize the following code using incSplitList:

```
tmpValue += incSplit[x][y] 
tmpValue2 += incSplit2[x][y]
tmpValue3 += incSplit3[x][y]
tmpValue4 += incSplit4[x][y]
tmpValue5 += incSplit4[x][y]
```

I am also using the new tmpValueList:

```
tmpValueList = [0] * nmbDurations
```

But I am confused in how to iterate through incSplitList while also accessing the elements x and y in the matrice like the code above:
So yeah long story short:
How is the below code to be compressed using the lists incSplitList and tmpValueList ?

```
tmpValue += incSplit[x][y] 
tmpValue2 += incSplit2[x][y]
tmpValue3 += incSplit3[x][y]
tmpValue4 += incSplit4[x][y]
tmpValue5 += incSplit4[x][y]
```

Comment: `incSplitList` created with a list `*` is a list with JUST one array, but multiple references to it.  List creation with `*` is tricky and often produces unexpected results.

Comment: Indexing a 2d array is best done with `incSplit[x,y]`.  The `[x][y]` approach works (sometimes) but is more typical of a list indexing.  If you created `arr=np.zeros((5,4,4))` you could skip all these temp names and iterations.

Comment: looks like you just want to `sum(incSplitList)`...

Answer (score 0):

Make a list of arrays

```
In [56]: alist = [np.arange(2*i,2*i+3) for i in range(3)]
In [57]: alist
Out[57]: [array([0, 1, 2]), array([2, 3, 4]), array([4, 5, 6])]
```

Since they are all the same size, we can make an array from the list:

```
In [58]: arr = np.array(alist)
In [59]: arr
Out[59]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

Access to an element:

```
In [60]: alist[2][1]
Out[60]: 5
In [61]: arr[2,1]
Out[61]: 5
```

Summing "rows":

```
In [62]: [sum(l) for l in alist]
Out[62]: [3, 9, 15]
```

But with the array we can sum columns or rows:

```
In [63]: arr.sum(axis=0)
Out[63]: array([ 6,  9, 12])
In [64]: arr.sum(axis=1)
Out[64]: array([ 3,  9, 15])
```

---

Don't use `*` to "replicate" lists, unless you know what you are doing, and it's intentional.

```
In [65]: blist = [np.zeros((2,2),int)]*3
In [66]: blist
Out[66]: 
[array([[0, 0],
        [0, 0]]),
 array([[0, 0],
        [0, 0]]),
 array([[0, 0],
        [0, 0]])]
In [67]: blist[1][1,:] = 3      # change one row of one element the list
In [68]: blist
Out[68]: 
[array([[0, 0],
        [3, 3]]),
 array([[0, 0],
        [3, 3]]),
 array([[0, 0],
        [3, 3]])]
```

See all the changes.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time and answering but I really dont understand the answer u gave me. What does in and out mean? what are the numbers 56 - 68

Comment: The `In`/Out` are line numbers from the `ipython` session where I ran this code.  The numbers are not significant except as references.  Unfortunately it is hard to tell how much you know, or not, about basic Python coding (or `numpy` on top of that).

Comment: Would it be possible to also just use ```for j in range(nmbDurations):
                                                              tmpValueList[j] += incSplitList[j][x][y] ```